# replace $scope.items on click of button

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have a list of items in an array in my scope.which is beeing repeated with ng repeat on my view. Now based on a click event i would like to filter the array to either show all or only my items. Whats the best way to do this?

Here is the button which i want to use to toggle between these two Arrays:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-custom1">
  <label class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="pL.myitems()" uib-btn-radio="'Middle'">Just mine</label>
  <label class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="pL.allitems()" uib-btn-radio="'Right'">All itmes</label>
</div>
```

in my controller on creating the object i extra create a backup scope variable, so i can always get back the original array($scope.items _all).

I try it this way, unfortunatly without success:

```
$scope.pL = {
        myitems: function () {
            $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.item_filter, { agent: uid });
        },
        allitems: function () {
            $scope.items = $scope.items_all;
        }
    };
```

Comment: You have a space here: `$scope.items _all`

Comment: corrected but that wasnt the issue!? Tnhx

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). With filters, you can define a function that, when passed an array, will return the array as you want it, without having to lose the original (and is easy to use and reuse in the view).

Example:

```
angular.module('yourModule')
.filter('arbitraryFilter', [function () {
        return function (inputArray, filterArray) {
            if(!filterArray) return inputArray; //This will return the unfiltered array.
            var resultArray = [];
            for(var i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++)
                if(inputArray[i].someProperty === 'property to include')
                    resultArray.push(inputArray[i]);
            return resultArray;
        };
    }])
.controller('yourController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.filterArray = false;
    $scope.toggleFilterArray = function(){ $scope.filterArray = !$scope.filterArray;};
}])
```

In your view:

```
<div ng-click="toggleFilterArray()">Toggle array filter</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in yourArray | arbitraryFilter:filterArray ">item.value</div>
```

As a last comment, I *heavily* suggest you don't use jQuery in an AngularJS app. There are whole articles on why you shouldn't mix them, and I'd honestly suggest you remove any jQuery you've already included and redo it in an Angular-oriented way.

Comment: got it!... my question is how can i now turn of this filter with ng-click?

Comment: Your additional parameter can be a boolean value. In the filter function, you can check it, and conditionally return the input array or a filtered version of it. Because it's a scope variable, you can modify the additional parameter's value in a function called by `ng-click`, and this should be reflected in the view immediately.

Comment: please provide a code example am not sure i get u right?!

Comment: I've modified my code slightly to reflect what it should look like. If the additional parameter is false, the original array will be returned, unfiltered. Otherwise, it will create a second array as the filtered version and return that, which will be displayed. As soon as you toggle the parameter, the view will update.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation;

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: uid as results">
```

in javascript :

```
$scope.pL = {
    myitems: function () {
        $scope.uid = 101 ; //enter your uid
     });
    },
    allitems: function () {
        $scope.uid = ""; //all
    }
};
```

Comment: got it!... my question is how can i now turn of this filter with ng-click?